# Simple C++ Program, kind of lost and need guidance

Tags: c++

I'm currently doing an assignment and I'm a bit lost on how to do it.

Here's the info on the assignment:

> Calculate the max, min, count, average, and standard deviation (std dev) of a set of numbers.
>
> The formula for average is:
>   average is sum divided by count
>
> The formula for standard deviation is: 
>   stddev is the square root of the variance
>
> The formula for variance is:
>   variance is (the sum of the squares divided by the count) minus the average squared.
>
> By the sum of the squares, I mean for a list like: 2 3 4, the squares are 4, 9, 16, and therefore the sum of the squares would be 29.
>
> When prompted "Enter Another? " Type n to leave the prompt and calculate the output values.  Type y, or any other single character to continue entering values.

And here's a screenshot/example run of the solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncHof.png

This is what I have so far

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double k;
char another;

int main()
{
    cout <<"\nEnter a number:";
    cin >> k;

    cout <<"\nEnter another?";
    cin >> another;

    if(another=="y")


double max,min,sum,average,standard,variance,count;

sum = k +

average = sum / count;

variance = 

    cout <<"\nMax Value:"<< max;
    cout <<"\nMin Value:"<< min;
    cout <<"\nCount:" << count;
    cout <<"\nAverage:" << average;
    cout <<"\nStd  Dev:"<< variance;

    return 0;
}`
```

1. How do I make it so if the user enters Y, he can enter another number like the assignments says to? And n to leave the prompt and calculate
2. How would I make it so it'll display the lowest and highest value for min/max?
3. How can I get the number of values entered for the count?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Look at your course material for loops.

Comment: One question per question please.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make it so if the user enters Y, he can enter another number like the assignments says to? And n to leave the prompt and calculate

You can put the program into a while loop, where if the user inputs an `n`, it will break out of the loop. Something along the lines of

```
bool inputting_Numbers = true;

while (inputting_Numbers) {

    // get data

    cin >> another;

    if (another == 'n')
        inputting_Numbers = false;

}

// calculations
```

Or, to make it even better, instead of asking the user if they want to enter another number, have it only break on a certain character, such as a `s` for stop or `b` for break.

```
bool inputting_Numbers = true;

while (inputting_Numbers) {

    // get data

    cin >> another;

    if (another == 'b' || another == 's')
        inputting_Numbers = false;

}

//calculations
```

You would also have to put the numbers into an array, or a vector. If you have a set of numbers, one variable isn't enough. Since you are using C++, I would recommend using vectors.

> How would I make it so it'll display the lowest and highest value for min/max?

You can create a function to find the smallest and biggest number of an array, or vector. Then just print it out.

> How can I get the number of values entered for the count?

If you are using a vector, you can just do

```
vectorName.size();
```

to get the amount of numbers. If you are using an array, you can get the amount of numbers by doing

```
int amount = sizeof(arrayName) / sizeof(int);
```

Comment: using breaks in while loops is bad programming. Better to have it set `inputting_numbers` to false instead so the loop can break naturally.

Answer (score 1):

You want a while loop to process each number individually, then after the user is finished, process the totals. Your algorithm is:

- set sums and things to 0
- start your while loop

  - get input
  - add to sum and sum_of_squares
  - increase count
  - check if max and min
  - ask to continue and stop while loop if the user doesn't
- calculate average and std_dev
- print everything

### The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
int main()
{
    float sum = 0;
    float sum_of_squares = 0;
    int count = 0;
    // Initialize max and min to things they can't possibly be
    float max = std::numeric_limits<float>::min();
    float min = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
    float num;
    bool done = false;
    char should_continue = 'y';

    while(should_continue != 'n')
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a number : ";
        std::cin >> num;

        //update sum and sum_of_squares and count

        //check if we've found a bigger or smaller number
        //if the number is bigger than max or smaller than min, update them

        std::cout << "Enter another? : ";
        std::cin >> should_continue;
        //if should_continue == n, the loop exits
    }

    //use our shiny info to get what we really want
    //Use your formulas and the sqrt() function from cmath to get answers

    std::cout << "Max : " << max << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Min: " << min << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Count: " << count << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Average: " << avg << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Std. Dev.: " << std_dev << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The OP clearly stated this is an assignment. It's one thing to provide guidance but you shouldn't be doing the assignment for them.